# How to make a module/java class publish A and subscribe for B simultaneously using zeroC IceStorm?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, ice

I have tried the IceStorm Clock demo app approach, but once it enters run(), it just stays there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from subscribing to an Ice topic and retrieving a topic proxy to another one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to handle multiple topic subscription, publishing of topics and even allow RPC communication. The sequence of the three communication types made a difference.